# How do I call a method from another solution to create a sort of data wrapper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple class for pulling data from a database that is linked to the ADO framework or whatever called OperationsEntities...

```
namespace DataModel
{
    public class PublisherData
    {
        public static List<Publisher> GetByID(int n)
        {
            using (OperationsEntities context = new OperationsEntities())
            {
                var query = from results in context.Publishers
                            where results.id == n
                            select results;
                List<Publisher> list = query.ToList<Publisher>();
                return list;
            }
        }

        public static List<Publisher> GetByName(string s)
        {
            using (OperationsEntities context = new OperationsEntities())
            {
                var query = from results in context.Publishers
                            where results.contact_name == s
                            select results;
                List<Publisher> list = query.ToList<Publisher>();
                return list;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to create a datawrapper in a business tier solution to pass this data from the data layer to the form layer (to make things nice and modular, and allow us to change the form layer to an online .NET app in the future, if we so desire, without having to rewrite everything.)

However, I can't seem to figure out how to use the GetByID and GetByName methods in my other class. I have the reference to my DataModel in my BusinessLogic namespace, and have "using DataModel;" at the top of my DataWrapper.cs.

I'm also struggling over the best way to handle the results. So far I'm trying to basically create a duplicate class of that on the DataModel that will just parse them out into a new class. So far, the skeleton for it is this...

```
namespace BusinessLogic
{
    class PublisherWrapper
    {
        int id;
        string publisherName;
        string address;
        string city;
        string state;
        string zip;
        string contact_name;
        string contact_phone;

        List<PublisherWrapper> list;

        public PublisherWrapper() { }

        public static List<PublisherWrapper> GetListByID(int n) 
        {
            List<Publisher> list = new List<Publisher>();

        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Any time I try to call the DataModel static methods it gives me the red squiggly of some kind of error, but doesn't provide any further information. Why can't I call those public static methods in my BusinessLogic solution?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to call PublisherData.GetById() and is there a red line under the using statement for the DataModel line?

Comment: The class is defined correctly, so something else has to be incorrect.  I'll echo Animal's request to see the code you are using to call the class.  Also, check to ensure that the reference to your Data Model assembly is correct.

Comment: I've tried Publisher.GetByID(n); GetByID(n); I've tried instantiating an object, just because (even though static shouldn't need it,) and DataModel.Publisher.GetByID(n); All of them have red squiggles under GetByID, the only methods intellisense shows are Equals and something else when I type out Publisher... No red squiggles under the using DataModel line. This is the first time I've split solutions, so I can only guess the reference is fine... I did a right click on BusinessLogic, add reference, selected Data, and it's now listed under "references."

Answer (score 0):

Try making your PublisherData class static. Also does your DataModel project currently build?

Comment: No, still the same results. I've tried calling it as Publisher.GetByID(n); as well, and that still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried building the whole solution, sometimes intellisense does not update when you think it should. Also did you add the reference as a dll or as a project? Are these both currently in the same solution?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, no. I don't know if I added it as a dll or a project... They're all part of the same project, just different solutions, as I understand the terminology. The reference shows up in the solution explorer under "references." And I added it by right clicking on the BusinessLogic solution, doing "add reference," then adding the DataModel solution.

Comment: OK a solution contains one or more projects.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, in the solution explorer it says "Solution 'SolutionName' (3 Projects)